# Display Access form on open & update textbox *while running other code*

Tags: vba, database, forms, ms-access, events

<sup>Sometimes trying to accomplish the most ***minor*** turns into a ***major*** headache...  I somehow corrupted a database while experimenting to solve *this* issue. Now I'm ***really*** determined to figure this out. (I'll worry about the corrupt DB later!)</sup>

### End Goal:

When opening `.accdb` file, automatically:

1. open form unbound)
2. run code to:

   - get `Last Update Date` from table
   - display `Last Update Date` in textbox on form *<sup>(must be visible to user)</sup>*
3. if table data is outdated, run code to:

   - update data in table
   - display `Update Progress Message(s)` in textbox on form *<sup>(must be visible to user)</sup>*
   - when finished:

     - display `Last Update Date` in textbox on form *<sup>(must be visible to user)</sup>*

---

The problem is the goal of *`(must be visible to user)`*.

I **can't get the form to display anything until all the code's finished running**, regardless of how I run the code (including: set the form to auto-open with <kbd>File</kbd> → <kbd>Options</kbd> → `Display Form`; add an `AutoExec` macro to call code to open the form and run the update; or, run it manually.)

---

I've been experimenting with the form's opening events to see if I missed something.

According to the **[Order of Events](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Order-of-events-for-database-objects-e76fbbfe-6180-4a52-8787-ce86553682f9#bm3)** documentation:

> ### Working with data on a form
>
> Form and control events occur as you move between records in the form and change data. For example, **when you first open a form**, the following sequence of events occurs:
>
> `Open` (form) → `Load` (form) → `Resize` (form) → `Activate` (form) → `Current` (form) → `Enter` (control) → `GotFocus` (control)

At no point does the form visibly update.  I've tried adding [`Me.Repaint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/form-repaint-method-access) and even tried [`Echo=True`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/application-echo-method-access) and [`DoEvents`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/doevents-function) but obviously they didn't change anything.

---

**My code for testing:**

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    txtTest = "Form_Open()": MsgBox "1. Form_Open"
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    txtTest = "Form_Load()": MsgBox "2. Form_Load"
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
    txtTest = "Form_Current()": MsgBox "3. Form_Current"
End Sub

Private Sub txtTest_Enter()
    txtTest = "txtTest_Enter()": MsgBox "4. txtTest_Enter"
End Sub

Private Sub txtTest_GotFocus()
    Echo True : Repaint : DoEvents
    txtTest = "txtTest_GotFocus()": MsgBox "5. txtTest_GotFocus"
End Sub

Private Sub txtTest_Change()                        : MsgBox "This Does't Run!" : End Sub
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()                      : MsgBox "This Does't Run!" : End Sub
Private Sub txtTest_Change()                        : MsgBox "This Does't Run!" : End Sub
Private Sub txtTest_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer) : MsgBox "This Does't Run!" : End Sub
Private Sub txtTest_AfterUpdate()                   : MsgBox "This Does't Run!" : End Sub
```

**The result of opening the form:**

[image: (animated screenshot)]

<sub>(Note that the form's `Activate` and `AfterUpdate` events and the control's `Change`, `BeforeEvent` and `AfterEvent` events do not fire at all.)</sub>

Theoretically, the form should be visible behind the `MsgBox`, but neither running the *actual* update code, nor running a "pause" (loop with `DoEvents`) doesn't display the form either.

I could *swear* I've done this in the past without issue but no matter what I do try, the form only displays once *all* code is finished running.

Comment: I can replicate this. That's how it is, I believe. Access 2016.

Comment: Are you saying that it's specific to Access 2016?

Comment: I often use the `Form_Timer` event to trigger code. Set the Form.TimerInterval to 1, and set it to 0 in the `Form_Timer` event.

Comment: No, but Access 2016 is what I tested with.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth  -  I gather that a form's initial "paint" doesn't occur until *all* of the forms' "opening events" have finished execution?  Do you know if this changed at some point?  I'm using Access 2016 and I might be mistaken but I could've *sworn* that in older versions (maybe 2007?) I was able to run code on open of the database and provide visible updates to the user.

Comment: I don't know the exacts about other versions, haven't been in the Access game for that long.

Comment: I always assume that anyone who's any good at Access is old like me  ⊙̯⊙

Comment: I'm sure I just set values in the form load event in Access 2010 without any issue. I'm about to update a pretty large database to 2016 so hope it don't cause any issues. Interesting.

Comment: I've just tested it and the form loads and display at Form Current and populates the textbox. This is in Access 2010. It would appear there is a difference in behaviour. that could be very annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Form_Timer` event to delay execution until the form fully finishes loading.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.TimerInterval = 1 'Trigger 1 millisecond, but asynchronously from other tasks
                         'Triggers after AutoExec macro has finished
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Timer()
   Me.TimerInterval = 0 'Trigger only once
   'Your other tasks here
End Sub
```

Comment: This method is easy to implement but I still have a feeling that the form can become visible during the Form_Load event.